# How to replace outliers with NA in R from vector created with boxplot()$out

Tags: r

I'd like to know how to replace outliers with "NA" in R, assuming that these outliers are stored in a vector created with boxplot()$out.

For example:

```
# create a data frame
df <- data.frame(Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group4", "Group4", "Group5", "Group5"), 
                 Value1 = c(48, 2, -130, 62, 3, 2, 8, 120, 2, 4), 
                 Value2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
> df
    Group Value1 Value2
1  Group1     48      1
2  Group1      2      2
3  Group2   -130      3
4  Group2     62      4
5  Group3      3      5
6  Group3      2      6
7  Group4      8      7
8  Group4    120      8
9  Group5      2      9
10 Group5      4     10

# plot the data frame
boxplot(df$Value1)

# create a vector of outliers for the numeric factor
outliers <- boxplot(df$Value1, plot = FALSE)$out

# view outliers
outliers
[1] -130  120
```

I have followed the instructions listed [here on RPubs](http://rpubs.com/Mentors_Ubiqum/removing_outliers) to get this far. 
Now, I would like to replace the outliers with "NA" instead of removing the rows they are in entirely so that I can keep data in the rows corresponding to the outliers from other columns that are not outliers in their respective factors (i.e. 3 and 8 in Value2). I'm assuming that `which` and `%in%` will come in to play here somewhere, but I'm stuck.

I need to know how to **replace** the values with NA so that I can later aggregate data from the same row in a different column (and also data from different rows in the same column).

I would like to replace the outliers with NA so that the data frame looks something like this:

```
> df
    Group Value1 Value2
1  Group1     48      1
2  Group1      2      2
3  Group2     NA      3
4  Group2     62      4
5  Group3      3      5
6  Group3      2      6
7  Group4      8      7
8  Group4     NA      8
9  Group5      2      9
10 Group5      4     10
```

I'm relatively new at programming in R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out using a base R solution.

```
# Replace the values with NA
df[df$Value1 %in% outliers, "Value1"] = NA
```

This replaces the outliers stored in the `outliers` vector with NA. However, it also changes the column to a `character` object. I need to change it back to numeric.

```
# no longer necessary but in case column attribute is altered
# Change column back to `numeric`
# df$Value1 <- as.numeric(df$Value1)
```

Voila. Problem solved.

Comment: You could just use NA without quotes to avoid the character conversion.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better, rather than replacing values, to add a new column that indicates whether those values are outliers (1) or not (0).

One base R way to do that:

```
df$is_outlier <- ifelse(df$Value1 %in% boxplot.stats(df$Value1)$out, 1, 0)
```

Result:

```
    Group Value1 Value2 is_outlier
1  Group1     48      1          0
2  Group1      2      2          0
3  Group2   -130      3          1
4  Group2     62      4          0
5  Group3      3      5          0
6  Group3      2      6          0
7  Group4      8      7          0
8  Group4    120      8          1
9  Group5      2      9          0
10 Group5      4     10          0
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you. However, this does not answer my question. I need to know how to replace the value with NA so that I can later aggregate the data across other columns.

Comment: Why do you need replacement with NA to do that? Perhaps edit your question to indicate the final output you would like. My feeling is that altering original values for this purpose is bad practice.

Comment: As I have stated in my question (edited), I need to replace the values with NA so that I can aggregate the data in that column. If others view this as a problem, a solution is to create a new data frame when making these changes so that you have a copy of one with the outliers and another with the outliers removed.