# How to detect and replace outlier from multiple columns in a single data set using R?

Tags: r, vectorization, outliers

I am trying to find and replace outliers from multiple numeric columns. This is not the best practice in my humble opinion, but it is something I'm attempting to figure out for specific use cases. A great example of creating an additional column that labels a row as an outlier can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993613/12224152) **but** it is based on a single column.

My data looks as follows (for simplicity, I excluded columns with factors):

```
   Row ID   Value1 Value2
      1        6      1
      2        2     200
      3      100      3
      4        1      4
      5      250      5
      6        2      6
      7        8     300
      8      600     300
      9        2      9
```

I used a function to replace outliers with NA in all numeric columns:

```
replaceOuts = function(df) {
    map_if(df, is.numeric, 
           ~ replace(.x, .x %in% boxplot.stats(.x)$out, NA)) %>% 
    bind_cols 
}
test = replaceOuts(df)
```

My question is how can I replace the outliers with another value (e.g., mean, median, capped value, etc.)? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some consider outliers those that are outside of 2 deviations from the mean, but that depends on your data (and assumes some sense of normality). Other than that, I think it relies on domain knowledge of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `NA` you could replace the value with `mean` or `median` whatever you prefer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

replaceOuts = function(df) {
   map_if(df, is.numeric, 
          ~ replace(.x, .x %in% boxplot.stats(.x)$out, mean(.x))) %>%
   bind_cols 
}

replaceOuts(df)

# RowID Value1 Value2
#  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1     6       1
#2     2     2     200
#3     3   100       3
#4     4     1       4
#5     5   108.      5
#6     6     2       6
#7     7     8     300
#8     8   108.    300
#9     9     2       9
```

Replace `mean` with `median` to any other function that you want.

PS - I think it is better to use `mutate_if` instead of `map_if` here since it avoids `bind_cols` at the end.

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(., . %in% boxplot.stats(.)$out, mean(.)))
```

Comment: Great point, [Ronak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah) - elegant!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need minVal and maxMax treshold values. And then replace values out of range (minVal, maxVal) with any value in myValue (mean, median o what you need)

```
# Could be any value for limits, i.e. 
minVal <- boxplot.stats(data$columnX)$stats[1]
maxVal <- boxplot.stats(data$columnX)$stats[5]
myValue <- median(data$columnX)

data[data$columnX < minVal | data$columnX > maxVal, "columnX"] <- myValue
```

Comment: This is makes sense and is good to have when a specific threshold is being used for my use cases