# How to create a boxplot or table that have labels of outliers and count the outliers?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, outliers

I'm not able to share my data, so sorry for that. Most of my data are either dummy or ordinal or unordered discrete variables. Only age is numeric.

I used this code to see which values are outliers

```
boxplot(df$var1, plot = TRUE)$out
```

And this code for count how many outliers:

```
length(boxplot(dataDK$sclmeet)$out)
```

I replaced the outliers with NA's using the sapply function.
I now want to either create boxplot or a table that count the amount of outliers and which they are. How is this possible?
If you help with the boxplot method then I can make mutilple boxplots and then combine them into one using `par(mfrow = c(,))`

The boxplot could look like this, where 1 (blue) is the value of outlier and 4 (blue) is the count of how many 1 there are:
[image: boxplot]

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I know this method:

```
out <- boxplot.stats(df$var1)$out

boxplot(df$var1,
  ylab = "var1",
  main = "Boxplot for var1"
)
mtext(paste("Outliers: ", paste(out, collapse = ", ")))
```

This will give a plot similary to this. However it is not a good method for many different outliers
(taken from [boxplot outlier labels](https://statsandr.com/blog/outliers-detection-in-r/)):
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of plots are easier with `ggplot`, not base R. Have you considered adding a table of your outliers next to your plot? There may be cases where you have different kinds of outliers (and thus your text would be cumbersome). However, if you already know how many outliers you have, you can use `annotate` to add simple text.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot) # to plot stuff side by side
library(gridExtra)

data(iris)
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Width, plot = TRUE)$out
length(boxplot(iris$Sepal.Width)$out)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993511/how-to-replace-outliers-with-na-in-r-from-vector-created-with-boxplotout
iris$is_outlier <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width %in% boxplot.stats(iris$Sepal.Width)$out, 1, 0)

iris <- iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Width, is_outlier) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Width_NA = ifelse(is_outlier == 1, NA, Sepal.Width))

t <- iris %>%
  filter(is_outlier == 1) %>%
  select(Sepal.Width) %>% table() %>% as.data.frame() %>% tableGrob(rows = NULL)
  
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Width_NA)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

# plot with table side-by-side
plot_grid(p, t, rel_widths = c(2, 1))
```

[image]

```
# close to your original desired plot
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Width_NA)) + 
  geom_boxplot()  + 
  annotate("label", color = "blue", 
           size = 4,
           x = 0, y = 2, 
           label = "1 (4)")
```

[image]